# Parsing text with regular expression into list with empty string in result

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to breakup/split a string into words.

```
    def breakup(text):
        temp = []
        temp = re.split('\W+', text.rstrip())   
        return [e.lower() for e in temp]
```

**Example Strings:**

**What's yellow, white, green and bumpy?     A pickle wearing a tuxedo**

**Result:**

**['what', 's', 'yellow', 'white', 'green', 'and', 'bumpy', 'a', 'pickle', 'wearing', 'a', 'tuxedo']**

but when i pass a string like

**How is a locksmith like a typewritter?     They both have a lot of keys!**

**['how', 'is', 'a', 'locksmith', 'like', 'a', 'typewritter', 'they', 'both', 'have', 'a', 'lot', 'of', 'keys', '']**

I want to parse in a way that it doesn't get empty string in the list.

The string passed will have punctuation etc. Any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change

```
return [e.lower() for e in temp]
```

to

```
return [e.lower() for e in temp if e]
```

---

Also, the line

```
temp = []
```

is not needed, since you never use the empty list you asign to `temp`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am wondering should i choose yours or JaredPar. As he mentioned len for empty string?

Comment: There's no need to use `len`, since an empty string is falsy (is this even a word?) by itself. I recommend [Alfe's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21385434/142637), using `findall` instead of `split`. Use should accept his answer IMHO.

Comment: The intended result is a list containing tokenized or parsed text, so why is finall better than split?

Comment: I jsut think it is a little bit clearer since you don't need the filtering after running the regex (unless you want to split on other things than just whitespace). OTHO, the code is quite simple and it probably boils down to your personal taste which one to use.

Answer (score 5):

How about searching for what you want:

```
[ s.lower() for s in
  re.findall(r'\w+',
    "How is a locksmith like a typewritter? They both have a lot of keys!") ]
```

Or to build just one list:

```
[ s.group().lower() for s in
  re.finditer(r'\w+',
    "How is a locksmith like a typewritter? They both have a lot of keys!") ]
```

Comment: +1 This is simpler than splitting and *then* filtering.

Comment: Yeah, I found the `\W` strange.  But maybe OP needs to split instead of search (that `\W` could have been just a simplified example).

Comment: findall seems indeed more appropriate than split in this case.

Comment: The intended result is a list containg tokenized or parsed text, so why is finall better than split?

Comment: I find it more readable (but that's a matter of taste, of course).  Actually, your thoughts should be focused on the words you want to process, not the not-words between them.  Have the code reflect that, and the next developer has a less hard time to understand your code.

Comment: And this way I don't need to test anything for being an empty string; the `+` in `\w+` ensures that I don't get anything empty.  If you specify the separator and use split, you cannot specify anything about the parts between the separators.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
txt='''\
What's yellow, white, green and bumpy? A pickle wearing a tuxedo
How is a locksmith like a typewritter? They both have a lot of keys!'''

import re

for line in txt.splitlines():
    print [word.lower() for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line) if word.strip()]
```

Prints:

```
['what', 's', 'yellow', 'white', 'green', 'and', 'bumpy', 'a', 'pickle', 'wearing', 'a', 'tuxedo']
['how', 'is', 'a', 'locksmith', 'like', 'a', 'typewritter', 'they', 'both', 'have', 'a', 'lot', 'of', 'keys']
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check for this in the list comprehension

```
return [e.lower() for e in temp if len(e) > 0]
```

Or for the pedantic out there

```
return [e.lower() for e in temp if e]
```

Comment: "if len(e) > 0" is not pythonic, "if e" would be enough

Comment: @DmitryVakhrushev given the question I wonder if the newbie might benefit from understanding what is going on under the hood by being more explicit

Comment: It can be pointed in comment. Teaching newbies bad practices is a bad practice.

Comment: @DmitryVakhrushev i fail to see how `len(e)` is a bad practice.  It's more explicit about what is happening here but in no way incorrect

Comment: JaredPar, I will accept Dominic Kexel's answer. I hope you wont mind. Thanks for your answer and clarification. He also mentioned about empty list etc.

Comment: @jamesT you should accept whatever answer you feel best helped you.  It's not going to offend me in the least

Comment: @JaredPar It isn't incorrect, it's just not a python style. There is an explicit recommendation in the [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) about this: "For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false."

Comment: IMHO both `len(e)` and `if e` are incorrect because `bool(' ')==True`

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```
'How is a locksmith <blah> a lot of keys!'.rstrip('!?.').split()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case it would be:

```
def breakup(text):
    temp = []
    temp = re.split('\W+', text.rstrip())   
    return [e.lower() for e in temp if e]
```

More general solution is:

```
>>> re.findall('\w+', 'How is a locksmith like a typewritter? They both have a lot of keys!') 
>>> ['How', 'is', 'a', 'locksmith', 'like', 'a', 'typewritter', 'They', 'both', 'have', 'a', 'lot', 'of', 'keys']
```